# jQuery or JavaScript: If string does not include this or that text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

In jQuery or JavaScript how would I test this kind of condition:

```
If myString does NOT include any of the following: "apple" or "orange" or "banana" Then
 Do stuff...
```

Thanks.

Comment: `if (!/apple|orange|banana/.test(myString)) { ... }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work;

```js
if ( myString !=='Apple' || myString !=='Orange' || myString !=='banana' ) {
// Do something
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks much!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
if((myString.contains("apple" || "orange" || "banana")) == false)
    return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try combining [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) with the [test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function.

```js
var containsApple = "this string contains apple";
var doesNotContainApple = "this is a test string."
var pattern = new RegExp(/apple|orange|banana/);

console.log("example 1 - '" + containsApple + "'");
//if it contains apple,orange or banana
if (pattern.test(containsApple)) 
  console.log("found apple in string") 
else
  console.log("Did not find apple in string")
  
console.log("example 2 - '" + doesNotContainApple + "'");
//If it doesnt contain any of the words
if (pattern.test(doesNotContainApple)) 
  console.log("found apple in string") 
else
  console.log("Did not find apple in string")
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel that the suggestions so far may have been a bit clunky. I propose:

```
const fruits = ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
const hasString = fruits.filter((fruit) => 'foobar'.indexOf(fruit) !== -1);

if (hasString.length < 1) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

This also gives you the added bonus of returning an array of what strings appear in your original string.